# Angular Router-outlet not populated in production mode

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to build my Angular app in production mode and encounter a weird error.

In development mode everything works fine. In production mode though, when I open "index.html", I am properly redirected to my desired default path but my **router-outlet** is not populated.

**My app-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GraphMapComponent } from './graph-map/graph-map.component';
import { ZoneEditorComponent } from './zone-editor/zone-editor/zone-editor.component';
import { ZonesOverviewComponent } from './zone-editor/components/zones-overview/zones-overview.component';
import { ZoneConfigurationComponent } from './zone-editor/components/zone-configuration/zone-configuration.component';
import { NewZoneSelectionComponent } from './zone-editor/components/new-zone-selection/new-zone-selection.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/zone-editor/zones', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'path-editor',
    component: GraphMapComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'zone-editor',
    component: ZoneEditorComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'zones',
        component: ZonesOverviewComponent,
        data: { animation: 'isLeft' }
      },
      {
        path: 'add-zone',
        component: NewZoneSelectionComponent,
        data: { animation: 'isRight' }
      },
      {
        path: 'zone/:id',
        component: ZoneConfigurationComponent,
        data: { animation: 'isRight' }
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'zones',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here you can see how the router-outlet does not get populated:
[image]

I have tried different things but I cannot figure it out. It works in dev-mode. It also works when I call `enableProdMode();` during `ng serve`.

**It only does not work when I use `build --prod` and do the minification/optimization/etc.**

Any help appreciated. I can provide more information when necessary, I'm just not sure which.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?  what did you do to fix it?   i'm stuck on this problem for now.

Comment: I am having this issue but I cannot work out why it isn’t working. Fine using ng serve but doesn’t work using ng build —prod. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue and had to disable aot and build optimization. I dont know why this has to be done and I think its super stupid but it was the only solution for me.

You can do this via angular.json. Just comment the two corresponding entries:

```
  [...]
  "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          //"aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          //"buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
    },
    [...]
```

or directly in the command line:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false --aot=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your production configured set correctly. I'm assuming you used Angular CLI to generate everything? For "build --prod" by default the target is set up in the workspace configuration such that all builds make use of bundling, limited tree-shaking, and also limited dead code elimination.

If something doesn't seem right look into the configuration and compare it to here 
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score 0):

Make one more file as environment.prod.ts

set production to true

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

Then run command

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: That was already the case. I also called enableProdMode() several times to test it. Prod **Mode** does not break my code. It has to do with the build